# OS X 10.6 on Mac Pro - Can My Dual Network Interfaces Be Made Assignable

Tags: macos, mac, networking

I've got a MacPro with two NICs on it. Is there anyway of telling OS X that  want to use them for differing applications?

E.g.

NIC1 - for web browsing and general use.
NIC2 - for downloads or a windows VM.

The only app I've encountered that offers this functionality is Parallels Desktop so it is obviously possible. Wondering if there is a system-wide implementation of this.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Personally, I don't see the benefit in the scenario you describe. Having two NICs attached to the same network, there's no advantage to using one only for web browsing and the other only for downloads and a VM.

Comment: @Zr40 - 'Benefit' is the in the eye of the beholder ;-)

Comment: What would be the benefit for you then? :)

Comment: That's between my and my P2P client ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

I played around with this for *months* under Azureus on OS X as it seems to allow traffic assignment by interface, ip, et. al. Unfortunately the last OS X JRE, as released, continued to lack support for this feature.

I think I know *exactly* what you're going for... One gateway has your name on it, and another (wireless, likely unsecured or wep), is available for more creative network activities. If your more private pursuits are actually worth being private, either VM an app dedicated to it or pick up a throwaway netbook and sit it next to the window.

Either way, do let us know if you make additional progress with this!